# Windows 10 - External precision touchpad - PTP

Tags: windows-10

I had to test our application with Windows 10 in-built multi finger touchpad solution. So I'm looking for a usb connected touchpad which is fully compatible with the "Precision touchpad" feature of Windows 10. Can anyone suggest one which is 100% working as expected?

Known NOT working:

- [Microsoft All-in-one media keyboard](https://www.microsoft.com/accessories/en-us/products/keyboards/all-in-one-media-keyboard/n9z-00001) - Source: Microsoft forum
- [Logitech K400](https://www.logitech.com/en-us/product/wireless-touch-keyboard-k400r) - Source: Microsoft forum
- [Jelly Comb touchpads](https://www.jellycomb.com/) - Source: Support confirmed for not working AS PTP
- [Wogek Touchpad](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07MQS4TCX) - Source: Support confirmed for not working AS PTP

Comment: multiple sources report some Jelly Comb touchpads do support PTP on W10. This one here specifies it in description https://www.amazon.com/Jelly-Comb-Touchpad-Multi-Touch-Navigation/dp/B06XGB8MN2?th=1, while this next one I asked the seller a question in spanish and he said "Yes" but then went back as saying "most of them", so I digress: https://www.amazon.es/dp/B07MMVZ9YR?ref_=pe_996661_48848311_dpLink and then there is the wireless version of that last one which I have no details about. The new Corsair K83 combo touchpad also states W10 gesture support

Comment: Thanks @leRobot. I have contacted with Jelly Comb support and they confirmed that their hardware is not "Precision Touchpad". It handles the gesture inside their hardware/driver and do not let Windows 10 to handle the touches as "Precision Touchpad". That Corsair K83 seems promising. Would be great to hear real feedback on this device. I ended up buying a touchscreen Dell P2418HT monitor and Virtual Touchpad feature works as expected. (The problem with non Precision touchpads that their simulate mousewheel event for example, while they shouldn't.)